# Check if database address value is empty in $collection?

Tags: magento2, php, database, sql, order-collection

How can I check if the field "company" contains a value or not, and set another value ("not a company" for instance) if empty?

```
class OrdersGrid
{
public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
{
    if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        return $collection;
    }

    if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
        $orderAddressTable  = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['oat' => $orderAddressTable],
            'oat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND oat.address_type = \'shipping\'',
            ['telephone', 'city', 'postcode', 'street', 'company']
        );
    }

    return $collection;
}
}
```